# Find all tuples related to a certain string in Python

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find all tuples related to a string, not just matched to it.
Here is what I made:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H'),('G','Z')]
init = 'A'

filtered_init = [item for item in data if item[0] == init or item[1] == init]
elements = list(dict.fromkeys([ i for i in chain(*filtered_init)]))
elements.remove(init)

dat = []
for i in elements:
    sync = [item for item in data if item[0] == i or item[1] == i]
    dat.append(sync)

print(dat)
```

The result is:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F')]
```

However, it only contains A-B-related level.
What I want to find is all tuples related to `init` string as described in the picture below:

[image]

In other words, `[('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H')]`
It is to find all edges reachable to `init`.
How can I get them?

Comment: Do you mean, this is a directed graph (or perhaps a tree), and you want to find all of the edges reachable from `A`?

Comment: Yes! I think I should clarify the post. Thanks for asking:)

Comment: Do you only want to follow the edges in the `(from, to)` direction, or is it an undirected graph?

Comment: Just the edges in the tuple format :)

Comment: I mean for example, if there was a tuple `('Z', 'H')`, would that make `'Z'` also related to `'A'`, or would it not count because the order is wrong?

Comment: Want to include the tuple ('Z', 'H') since it is related to init keyword 'A'.

Comment: you are looking for the connected component of a graph, which is typically found by an unbounded breadth-first-search, or a floodfill algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is to find the [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of `init` in an undirected graph defined by an [edge list data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_list).

This data structure is not very convenient to use for this problem, so the first step is to transform it into an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). From there, we can apply any standard [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) algorithm, such as [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Once we're done, we can transform the result back into the edge list format you want for your output.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def find_connected_component(edge_list, start):
    # convert to adjacency list
    edges = defaultdict(list)
    for a, b in edge_list:
        edges[a].append(b)
        edges[b].append(a)

    # depth-first search
    stack = [start]
    seen = set()

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node not in seen:
            seen.add(node)
            stack.extend(edges[node])

    # convert back to edge list
    return [ edge for edge in edge_list if edge[0] in seen ]
```

Usage:

```py
>>> find_connected_component(data, init)
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F'), ('F', 'W'), ('W', 'H')]
```

Comment: Now, I am just wondering how to deal with the case in which if there was a tuple ('Z', 'H'), it would not count, meaning the order matters. Can you please explain it too?

Comment: Simply delete the line `edges[b].append(a)`. That line inserts an edge going "the other way" to make the graph undirected; if you take it out then you have a directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

A very naive solution, might not be efficient for complicated trees.

```
data = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F'),
        ('F', 'W'), ('W', 'H'), ('G', 'Z')]
init = ['A']
result = []
while init:
    initNEW = init.copy()
    init = []
    new = 0
    for edge in data:
        for vertex in initNEW:
            if edge[0] == vertex:
                result.append(edge)
                init.append(edge[1])
                new += 1
    for i in range(len(result) - new, len(result)):
        data.remove(result[i])
print(result)
# [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F'), ('F', 'W'), ('W', 'H')]
```

Answer (score 0):

For more efficient, you might use [DSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). This solution works O(N)

```
from functools import reduce
import random

parent = dict()
init = 'A'
data = [('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H'),('G','Z')]

def make_set(v):
    parent[v] = v

def find_set(v):
    if v == parent[v]:
        return v
    parent[v] = find_set(parent[v])
    return parent[v]

def union_sets(a, b):
    a, b = map(find_set, [a, b])
    if a != b:
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            a, b = b, a
        parent[b] = a;

elements = set(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, data))

for v in elements:
    parent[v] = v

for u, v in data:
    union_sets(u, v)

init_set = find_set(init)
edges_in_answer = [e for e in data if find_set(e[0]) == init_set]
print(edges_in_answer)
```

Output: *[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F'), ('F', 'W'), ('W', 'H')]*

Comment: Are you sure this is more efficient? According to my benchmark, this solution is about 3 times slower than DFS. Asymptotically, DFS is O(n) but this is actually slightly higher than O(n) because the disjoint-set data structure's operations are not quite O(1).

Comment: By the way, using `reduce` to join the tuples together is O(n^2); better to use `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))`.

Comment: Probably, yes. I assume the bottleneck in this code is to store strings in `parent`. And it isn't exactly right. However, dsu asymptotically better than dfs, isn't it?

Comment: No, DFS is O(m + n) on a graph with m vertices and n edges. In this problem, only the edge list is provided, so the number of vertices is strictly at most the number of edges, hence DFS is O(n). In comparison, your algorithm does O(n) DSU operations, so its complexity is O(n alpha n) where alpha is the inverse Ackermann function. This is slightly more than O(n), and for practical purposes we can call it O(n), but that only equals DFS asymptotically. See https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~sanjeev/papers/soda14_disjoint_set_union.pdf for the analysis of your data structure which randomises linking.