# Depth first search to find tuples by a string in Python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to build DFS program dealing with a (from to) tuple list as below:

```
data = [('X','A'),('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H'),('TY','H'),('CS','H')]
searchkey = 'B'
```

What to have is:

```
[('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H')]
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Here is the reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/

Comment: This seems to be a literal duplicate of another question.  Looks like your classmate got to SO first.  ;-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081126/find-all-tuples-related-to-a-certain-string-in-python

Comment: I think your output is incorrect? Don't you want to have every tuple which contains the `searchkey`? In any case, see my answer below which should be the correct output.

Comment: why you have these `('F','W'),('W','H')` in your result?? your search key is `'B'`

Comment: @NicholasM even though the other question doesn't mention DFS, that's what the OP is indeed looking for and so I agree with the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

`[item for item in data if 'B' in item]`

result :

`[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F')]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def BFS(data, key):
    return [i for i in data if key in i]

data = [('X','A'),('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('B','F'),('F','W'),('W','H'),('TY','H'),('CS','H')]
searchkey = 'B'

output = BFS(data, searchkey)
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'F')]
```